# Spin dependent Andreev refelction

Tags: scattering, superconductivity

What happens with the spin in Andreev reflection process ? The simple Bogoliubov - De Gennes equation for hole and electron does not contain information about the spin. I know there are some generalizations to spin dependent formalism but I can't find good refrence. Can You recommend good papers/books about spin dependent scattering processes - spin dependent Andreev reflection (when it changes or not); spin physics in proximity of superconductor.

Comment: I have the same problem, all of the good papers require you to purchase them(and they are not cheap). Good luck.

Comment: Try this [thesis](http://www.tifr.res.in/~superconductivity/pdfs/goutamsheet.pdf), appendix $5.1$ page $106$, in chapter $5$, page $87$ and followers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BdG equation reads, in full spin-space, and for a *s*-wave superconductors

$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
H_{0}\left(p\right) & 0 & 0 & \Delta\\
0 & H_{0}\left(p\right) & -\Delta & 0\\
0 & \Delta^{\ast} & -H_{0}^{\ast}\left(-p\right) & 0\\
-\Delta^{\ast} & 0 & 0 & -H_{0}^{\ast}\left(-p\right)
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
u_{\uparrow}\left(p\right)\\
u_{\downarrow}\left(p\right)\\
v_{\uparrow}\left(-p\right)\\
v_{\downarrow}\left(-p\right)
\end{array}\right)=\varepsilon\left(\begin{array}{c}
u_{\uparrow}\left(p\right)\\
u_{\downarrow}\left(p\right)\\
v_{\uparrow}\left(-p\right)\\
v_{\downarrow}\left(-p\right)
\end{array}\right)$$

so it is quite often (always ?) decoupled as you most probably seen it in two spin sectors

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
H_{0}\left(p\right) & \Delta\\
-\Delta^{\ast} & -H_{0}^{\ast}\left(-p\right)
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
u_{\uparrow}\\
v_{\downarrow}
\end{array}\right)=\varepsilon\left(\begin{array}{c}
u_{\uparrow}\\
v_{\downarrow}
\end{array}\right)$$

and $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
H_{0}\left(p\right) & -\Delta\\
\Delta^{\ast} & -H_{0}^{\ast}\left(-p\right)
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
u_{\downarrow}\\
v_{\uparrow}
\end{array}\right)=\varepsilon\left(\begin{array}{c}
u_{\downarrow}\\
v_{\uparrow}
\end{array}\right)$$

and we verify the usual dispersion $\varepsilon^{2}=H_{0}^{2}+\left|\Delta\right|^{2}$ when $H_{0}^{\ast}\left(-p\right)=H_{0}\left(p\right)$.

Now for a free-electron gas with BCS-paring, one has $H_{0}\left(p\right)=p^{2}/2m-\mu\approx v_{F}\left(p-p_{F}\right)$ and the Andreev reflexion of a spin-up electron at wave-vector $+k$ is a spin-down hole at wave-vector $-k$ at a N/S interface. So at the interface there is neither momentum ($+k+(-k)=0$), nor spin ($\uparrow +\downarrow = 0$) accumulation. There is nevertheless a charge accumulation ($-e-(+e)=-2e$, aha ! the charge of a Cooper pair !), see the seminal paper by [Tinkham, Blonder and Klapwijk](http://scholar.google.fr/scholar?q=author%3Atinkham%20author%3Ablonder%20author%3Aklapwijk&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5) (actually, Klapwijk is still working (well, I've seen a paper from his group this week on the arXiv), so contact him to see his paper if you have trouble with the pay-wall, he's at TU-Delft, the Netherlands).

The reason why no-one discusses spin-problem with *s*-wave superconductor is because of the singlet pairing, so there is no spin-accumulation at the S/N interface.

Spin-problem in proximity with superconductors have a few reviews:

> A.I. Buzdin, RMP **77** 935 (2005) [arXiv:cond-mat/0505583](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0505583)
>
> F. S. Bergeret,  A. F. Volkov, K. B. Efetov, RMP **77** 1321 (2005) [arXiv:cond-mat/0506047](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0506047)

well, spin here means *ferromagnet* (generically called S/F proximity effects), but the topic is pretty broad now, so precise your question after looking at these papers. You can try also the keywords *spintronic* and *superconductivity*, you may find some things interesting for you.

I remember I pretty liked a book by Ketterson and Song, Cambridge University Press, (well, a fully inspired name:) *Superconductivity* (tadam !). They review the BdG formalism for (all?, I don't remember, sorry) coupling in a superconductor.

Comment: As usually, FraSchelle saves my life :)